# Java passing commands to the terminal difference

Tags: java, terminal, command, difference

I want to talk to the program cordova in Java. In the terminal I can do this to get the version:

```
cordova -v
```

and in the terminal will return:

```
3.4.1-0.1.0
```

But if I ask Java to run `cordova -v` It returned Error: `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cordova": error=2, No such file or directory.`
 I tried this in the terminal:

```
/usr/local/bin/cordova -v
and it still returned:
3.4.1-0.1.0
```

But when I asked Java to run `/usr/local/bin/cordova -v` it didn't return *anything*. Got a fix for my problem?

**Edit**

Pasted from comment

I'm calling my runShell function like

```
runShell("cordova -v"); 

private String runShell(String command) { 
   StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer(); 
   Process p; 
   try { 
       p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); 
       p.waitFor(); 
       BufferedReader reader = 
           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
       String line = "";     
       while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) { 
           output.append(line + "\n"); 
       }  
   } catch (Exception e) { 
       System.out.println(e); return "Error: " + e; 
   }

   return output.toString(); 
}
```

Comment: How did you ask Java to run cordova?  Hard to tell what you're doing wrong when you don't show what you're doing.

Comment: David I can paste my whole code to what im doing :) I'm calling my runShell function: runShell("cordova -v"); I pasted my runShell function into my question

Comment: Is cordova printing its output to standard out or to standard error? You might want to try `getErrorStream` in place of `getInputStream` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Changing Input to Error stream gave me an error: "env: node: No such file or directory". Does that mean something important?

Comment: Do you mean that was the output from cordova?  If so, I can't help.  I don't know how cordova works.

Comment: no that was the output from the terminal received from java

Comment: So it didn't come via the InputStreamReader?

Comment: It was the output from getErrorStream() (The value then the function returns)

Comment: Right.  So it came from cordova.  As I said, I can't help with that.

Comment: Ohh I didn't know that means it came from cordova. Thats ok thats a lot David. I just thought my java method would do the EXACT same same thing as writing it in the terminal and thats what I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{ "/usr/local/bin/cordova", "-v" });
```

You have to pass the command and each of its arguments separately, because you're not invoking a shell to parse the command line for you.

Comment: I tried that and it did the exact same thing. I changed runShell to take a String array and called runShell(new String[]{"/usr/local/bin/cordova", "-v"}) and it didn't return anything still